# Cannot view .csproj in Gitkraken

Tags: git, encoding, visual-studio-2017, csproj, gitkraken

I have a .csproj file and can't open it in Gitkraken because it says "Cannot show changes in binary file".

At the moment my .csproj file starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Previously it was `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` but I changed it in order to expirement. No luck however...

We're sitting on Windows using Git. The file can be perfectly opened in Visual Studio Code or notepad. It's just that Gitkraken chooses not to.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: It's one of the reasons I gave up using built-in diff tools of Visual Studio, GitKraken and SourceTree, they all suck. Get yourself a copy of Beyond Compare or any other tool that does diffing right, as opposed to those half-assed attempts at diff viewers built in tools whose primary value lies not within rendering diffs. Also don't bother mailing GitKraken, they never respond.

Comment: @CodeCaster How do I set a difftool in Gitkraken? I only see an option to select merge tool.

Comment: It's not possible. I've requested that per mail on March 30th and never even received a response apart from the autoreply, so I gave up on using that tool. Went back to SourceTree.